# How to solve "npm ERR! code 1" when running npm install

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, npm-install

I'm getting npm ERR! code 1 when running n`pm install in a Laravel Project, specificly with this
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed

Laravel version: 5.2

I've tried with:

- Node v14.*, v12.2.*, v11.*
- NPM vlatests, NPM v6.*

I've tried almost every solution in stack overflow forums, cleaning npm cache, removing .lock files, cleaning composer cache, composer autoload, etc... nothing works

Here's the output code

```
    npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' +
npm ERR! gyp verb cli     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',        
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.2.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" 
in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2     
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n  
  at getNotFoundError (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' 
+
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' 
+
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' 
+
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n' +npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver ' 
+
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     'Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)',
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python38\python.EXE       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Fiver Projects\\yuryhoyos\\Backend\\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\Fiver Projects\yuryhoyos\Backend\rakzodia-ethos-backend-7128da03c67c\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\javie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-04T03_07_28_962Z-debug.log
```

Here's the package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Any ideas of how can I solve it??

Comment: The error log says it's looking for python2, you have python3 installed on your computer

Answer (score 0):

node-gyp has a prerequisite for python. However, going through logs, i noticed you have python 3.8 already installed.

The problem here is that the version of node-gyp you have is 3.8, which is not compatible with python 3, which can be noted by print syntax error

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The latest version of node-gyp is 8.1.0, find it's detail [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

*Solution*

1. You can update node-gyp to the latest version, from 3.8 to 8.1. If you are working in a team, everyone will have to do this in their machine
2. You can downgrade your python 3.8 to python 2, or keep both the version, which requires extra efforts of setting environmental variable correctly